# Obj-C iOS Delete UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Im trying to delete a UITableViewCell from a table. I am having a problem because sometimes the cell that I want to delete has been scrolled off the screen and potentially recycled. I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]

The delete method works perfectly if the deleted cell is visible in the tableview.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

the best way to delete a cell is to delete first the item in your data source (NSmutableArray)  and then delete the cell or reload your uitableview

`[yourArray removeObjectAtIndex:yourIndex];
[yourTableView reloadData];`

Answer (score 0):

Surely you populate your UITableView with data, right? This data most likely comes from a container class like an NSArray or something like that, I presume. Merely delete the item of data from the NSArray and update the number of rows in section with the new number of items. Don't try to delete the UITableViewCell if it is off-screen.